# Wordpress homepage with text displayed from php code snippets not updating in real time

Tags: php, wordpress, code-snippets

I have a wordpress website which uses two php code snippets on the homepage that reference a database and echo data based on the database entries. I'm using the 'Code Snippets' plugin to store the code, and use a text editor element in Elementor Pro where I use the shortcode dynamic tag to insert the code snippet and display the result.

The text should update as the database is updated but I've found that there is a fairly significant delay between the database updating and the homepage text reflecting the update. I am new to this so am not sure what the cause of this may be.

I have considered clearing the cache of the device being used to view the site, that doesn't seem to be it. I have also considered that using a cron schedule to force the website to redo the code snippet although I'm not sure how to implement this.

Does anyone know what could be causing this and how I might fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is, despite your considerations, most likely a cache issue. If you update information in the database, when the query runs, you will get that data. If you aren't seeing an immediate change, that means the query has been cached, or the browser has cached the data. It might not be the browser's cache. Could be the server, could be DNS (if something like Cloudflare is serving the page). You can look in the dev tools in the browser - if you look at the main URL request, it will tell you if the cached version is being served.

Comment: Thanks very much for explaining that, I will take a look at the things you've suggested.

Comment: This worked, I am using a wordpress plugin to clear the cache at regular intervals. Thanks!